# How to inject datefilter in protractor?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, protractor

I am writing end to end test cases for my angular application. I need to check for dates that are in correct format. So I want to inject the 'datefilter', so that I can use it in protractor.

When i 'googled' i found that i can use the browser.executeAsyncScript to get the injector and then use

```
angular.injector(["ng"]).get("dateFilter");
```

to get the datefilter.

But i am still not able to put them all together in code. 
Any heads-up would be enough to get me going with the code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Theoretically you can access your services like this:

```
browser.executeAsyncScript(function(callback) {
  var service = angular.injector(['MyModule']).get('myService');
  service.query({}, function(data) {
    callback(data);
  });
}).then(function (output) {
  console.log(output);
});
```

And there is an example:

https://github.com/andresdominguez/protractor-meetup/blob/master/test/e2e/api-helper.js

Comment: I saw this. This is where i was having trouble. I could not get the date filter and use it in the tests. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

@Lajos Veres, your answer was helpful. Finally used that to get a correct implementation.

```
browser.executeScript(function() {
  var myDateFilter = angular.injector(["ng"]).get('dateFilter');
  var dateString = myDateFilter(new Date(), 'EEE, dd MMM yy');
  return dateString;
})
.then(function(dateStr) {
    .... //use dateStr for whatever required.
});
```

Comment: Really? You posted this as the accepted answer instead of posting it as a comment and accepting Lajos' answer? Downvoting for that.